# Event Add Android device Calendar App 4.0

Tags: android, calendar

I want to add Event in Android device calendar App 4.0 .If I use ID=1 in Calendar API then Event successfully add but if i use different id then event does not add in calendar app. Any suggesstion would be appriciable. Thanks in advance I use Following code

```
long ids = -1;
long startMillis = 0; 
long endMillis = 0; 
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance(); 
//beginTime.set(2013, 10, 29, 5,40); 
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis(); 
 Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance(); 
// endTime.set(2013, 10, 30, 4, 20);
 endMillis= endTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// Insert Event
cr=getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, eventId);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis+60*60*1000);
//values.put(CalendarContract.Events.STATUS, "null");
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, tz.getID());

Uri uri = cr.insert(
        CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: how can i add an event to devise calendar without showing the calendar in android in single button click pass all details to devise calendar my code like this:                                           ContentResolver cr=getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1));
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, outPut.getEventTitle());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, c1.getTimeInMillis());
Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure the Calendar ID which you are inserting data exists :

check once :

```
public void getCalendarsList() {
    String[] projection = new String[]{"_id"};
    Uri calendars;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8 ) {
        calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
    } else {
        calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
    }
    Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(calendars, projection, null, null, null);    //get all calendars
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String calId;
        int l_idCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
        do {
            calId = cursor.getString(l_idCol);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    }
```

Comment: I want to add event without using Cursor so please tell me how to add event without Cursor

Comment: You don't have to just query and check whether calendar id exists before adding